# Shadcn using Select component inside form not setting value

Tags: next.js13, react-select, zod

So I am using a form component from Shadcn, which contains `Input`, `Select` and `Checkbox`components.

The `Input` and `Checkbox` components are working fine and there are no issues with them, which makes me think its something to do with the `Select` component.

I have setup a `FormSchema`:

```
const formSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(1),
  firstname: z.string().min(1),
  lastname: z.string().min(1),
});
```

I then setup the `useForm` hook:

```
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
  resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
  defaultValues: {},
});
```

I then have a useEffect which checks to make sure that we have got the user information from the database, if we do I set the values of the form:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (dbUser) {
    form.setValue("title", dbUser.title);
    form.setValue("firstname", dbUser.firstname);
    form.setValue("lastname", dbUser.lastname);
  }
}, [dbUser]);
```

Now as I mentioned the `firstname` and `lastname` are inputs and this works fine, but the `title` is a `Select` component:

```
<FormField
    control={form.control}
    name="title"
    render={({ field }) => {
      return (
        <FormItem>
          <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
          <Select
            onValueChange={field.onChange}
            defaultValue={field.value}
            value={field.value}
          >
            <FormControl>
              <SelectTrigger>
                <SelectValue placeholder="Select" />
              </SelectTrigger>
            </FormControl>
            <SelectContent>
              <SelectItem value="Doctor">Doctor</SelectItem>
              <SelectItem value="Mr">Mr</SelectItem>
              <SelectItem value="Mrs">Mrs</SelectItem>
              <SelectItem value="Miss">Miss</SelectItem>
            </SelectContent>
          </Select>
          <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
      );
    }}
  />
```

When debugging the issue, if I navigate to the page using a standard `router.push` the `Select` component will not populate, when I refresh the page though the `Select` component does select the correct value?

Comment: When I was using Select, I didn't have to use value={field.value}, it worked without it. May it be the case for you?